# A verb for when mistrust increases?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, idiomatic-language

> After what he did, her mistrust in their relationship _______ .
>
> So they already had mistrust in this agreement, but with the recent turns of events their mistrust ______ .
>
> If you do that, their mistrust in you would ______ .

I thought about "empower", "increase", and "raise". What is an idiomatic verb for such contexts?

Answer (score 2):

I would use **grow**:

> After what he did, her mistrust in their relationship *grew*.
>   So they already had mistrust in this agreement, but with the recent turns of events their mistrust *grew*.
>   If you do that, their mistrust in you would *grow*.

---

From Merriam-Webster's entry for [*grow*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grow):

> **2 b** : INCREASE, EXPAND
>   // *grows* in wisdom